# Получение доступа с помощью cookies к защищённому api через oauth2.0 openid connect server. Клиенты asp.net core mvc, react js - вместе и отдельно

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth2, core

Может кто делал сервер авторизации на asp net core с использованием openiddict, asp net core mvc с react js (в одном приложении и по отдельности), сервер ресурсов (защищённое api) и всё это работало через cookies?
Сервер аутентификации - OpeniddictServer. Сервер ресурсов - ResourceServer.
Пример тут с ангуляром, брал его за основу: https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreOpeniddict (это не мой проект. Но я взял его за основу и переделываю).
Вот так я настраивал клиента:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(config =>
{
    config.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    config.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44395";
    options.ClientId = "platform-net-6";
    options.ClientSecret = "123456789";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.AutomaticRefreshInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
   
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    options.Scope.Add("dataEventRecords");
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = $"https://localhost:44395",
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
    };
});
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7256", "https://localhost:44390")
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowCredentials();
});


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Я уже пол инета перелазил и только что-то такое нашёл. Кто чем может - просьба помочь.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.